# converting pd.Series of strings into ndarray

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, reshape2

I extract an array of words from pandas column:

```
X = np.array(tab1['word'])
```

> example of X :  array(['dog', 'cat'], dtype=object)

X is a pandas Series of 665 strings.
And then I transform each word into an ndarray of (1,270)

```
for i in range(len(X)):
    tmp = X[i]
    z = func(tmp) #function that returns ndarray of (1,270)
    X[i] = z
```

My end goal is to get an Ndarray of shape: (665, 270)
but instead I get this shape: (665,)
And I also can't reshape it, when I try to: `X.reshape(665,270)`
I get this error:

```
ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 665 into shape (665,270)
```

The `func(word)` function could be any function, for example:

```
def func(word):
    a = np.arange(0,270)
    a = a.reshape(1,270)
    return a
```

Any ideas on why is it so?

Comment: Please post a minimal, verifiable and complete example. At the moment we would have to guess what the problem is

Comment: I added more details

Answer (score 1):

The problem is about converting a Pandas Series of strings into a NumPy array by a transformative function that, given a string input, returns a (1, n) array.

Here is the solution:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# You have a series of strings
X = pd.Series(['aaa'] * 665)

# You have a transformative func that returns a (1, n) np.array
def func(word, n=270):
    return np.zeros((1, n))

# You apply the function to the series and vertically stack the results
Xs = np.vstack(X.apply(func))

# You check for the desidered shape
print(Xs.shape)
```

Answer (score -1):

The key lines below are:

```
z = list(func(tmp)) # converting returned value from func to a list
```

and

```
result = np.array([x for x in X.values])
```

Here is my full test code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


def func(tmp):
    return np.array([t for t in tmp])


X = pd.Series({'a': 'abc', 'x': 'xyz', 'j': 'jkl', 'z': 'zzz'})
for i in range(len(X)):
    tmp = X[i]
    z = list(func(tmp)) # converting returned value from func to a list
    X[i] = z

result = np.array([x for x in X.values])
```

Then type result on console, you'll see it is an (4, 3) ndarray.

```
In[3] result
Out[3]: 
array([['a', 'b', 'c'],
       ['x', 'y', 'z'],
       ['j', 'k', 'l'],
       ['z', 'z', 'z']], dtype='<U1')
```